# Appending items to a knockout array?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to take an observable containing an array (not observableArray, but can change this if needed), and append items of the same type to the array, without doing a foreach and notifying subscribers for each new item pushed.

I've tried a few different methods per posts found on SO and github, but nothing I've tried seems to work.  I can replace the contents without any issues - it's just adding items that I've having a problem with.

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ckMJE/236/

I also tried this to no avail:

```
 self.colors.push.apply(self.colors,self.newColors);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Code:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    this.self = this;
    self.index = ko.observable(0); // default
    self.newColor = ko.observable("purple"); // default
    self.newColors = ko.observable([{
        color: 'it'
    }, {
        color: 'is'
    }, {
        color: 'working'
    }]);
    self.colors = ko.observable([{
        color: 'red'
    }, {
        color: 'blue'
    }, {
        color: 'yellow'
    }]);
    self.addSome = function () {
        ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.colors, self.newColors);
    };
    self.replace = function () {
        self.colors(self.newColors());
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go...just need to fiddle with your arrays then pass the combined array back over to your observable in question.

http://jsfiddle.net/ckMJE/247/

```
    self.addSome = function () {
        var oldArray = self.colors(),
            newArray = self.newColors(),
            combinedArray = oldArray.concat(newArray);
        self.colors(combinedArray);
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

1) You need to unwrap your array, operate on it, and only then set the observable to the altered array:

```
self.addSome = function () {
    self.newColors(ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.colors(), self.newColors()));
};
```

2) Unless your second line of code is a typo, you've inadvertently made `self` a global, which will cause you lots of trouble if you eventually use nested viewmodels.

Comment: There actually is already a global `self`, which is why this code can run at all. Line 2 sets a `self` property on the viewmodel, and the rest are operating on the global `self`, which means that all the properties are actually global.